# How to use MoveIt without a real or simulated robot

Tags: ros, path-planning, moveit, ros-kinetic, movegroup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

is there a way to simply do the path planning of a robot with moveit with a given URDF without the execution part of the robot? I dont want to supply any `FollowJointTrajectoryActions` or `JointStates`. I am just interested in the path which was found by moveit path planning.
I am currently using the Python version of the MoveGroupCommander which seem to require a real or simulated robot with joint states and follow joint trajectory actions.
Is there a way to simply do the `path planning part` with python?

Thanks for the answers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310201/how-to-use-moveit-without-a-real-or-simulated-robot/) by [nmelchert](https://answers.ros.org/users/29154/nmelchert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2018-12-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look at how `demo.launch` sets this up.

---

Edit: btw, your question seems to be more about "how to use MoveIt without a real or simulated robot" than "path planning without execution".

The former is something that `demo.launch` does, the latter can be done by calling `plan(..)` instead of one of the other functions.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nmelchert](https://answers.ros.org/users/29154/nmelchert/) on 2018-12-07**:
Thank you!. `the demo.launch` setup was exactly what I was looking for.

**Comment by [gonzalocasas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34021/gonzalocasas/) on 2019-05-05**:
@nmelchert we work on basically that exactly use case ("path planning part with python"). We publish a few [docker compose files](https://github.com/gramaziokohler/ros_docker) for that purpose which are used from a [python open source framework](https://github.com/gramaziokohler/compas_fab) we published last year. Here are some [code examples](https://gramaziokohler.github.io/compas_fab/latest/examples/03_backends_ros/04_plan_motion.html) in case you are still interested.